# Reduction of binary number

Tags: functions, binary

I want to compress a binary number (e.g $128$ bit number) to a less bit number. It number should be send and again converted to initial number ($128$ bit)

Comment: You do not specify whether the space of 128 bit numbers you want to compress includes *all* 128 bit numbers or only an identifiable (and small) subset of those numbers.

Comment: Compression schemes often (almost invariably) take advantage of a nonuniform distribution among the keys (here, the 128 bit numbers) to be transmitted.  By using shortened versions for the most common keys and lengthened versions for the least common keys, it is usually possible to obtain substantial compression ratios.  However it is not possible to "compress" (shorten) all the keys with a common scheme.

Comment: @EricTowers I want to compress all 128 bits to less binary number (e.g 110 bits) but to have possibility to back to same value

Comment: @hardmath Do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you permit any additional communication between the sender and receiver other than the $110$ bits?

Comment: I have better than an idea.  I know with mathematical certainty that it is impossible to map all the 128 bit numbers to 127 or fewer bit numbers in a reversible way.  Hint: There are twice as many 128 bit numbers as there are 127 bit numbers.

Comment: @EricTowers I dont understand you?

Comment: @EricTowers Could be, but I wand to reduce bit comsumption

Answer (score 1):

Interpolating information from comments with the question...

Since you require that all possible $128$ bit strings be encodable, you do not allow any string to become longer in encoding, and you do not allow an additional round of communication to transmit additional bits, what you want is impossible.

The only way to share the answers to $128$ independent yes/no questions with another party is to tell them all $128$ answers.

Comment: Nothing else to do?

Comment: You have 128 bits of entropy to communicate.  Your answers to the comments to your Question leave no alternative but to transmit all 128 of them.  Imagine the simpler problem:  you want to transmit two bits.  Can you reversibly encode the four states of two bits into a single yes/no question (a.k.a, one bit)?

Comment: Yes but here we have 128 bits, no 2 bits :)

Comment: @John988 : And that matters why?  You cannot pour 10 liters into a 5 liter bucket.